# Populating List of Objects using constructor with parameters

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to populate list of class Student:

```java
class Student {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
```

Here is the generator method signature:

```java
public List<Student> generateRandomStudents(int quantity) {
List<Student> students;
// List is populated by required quantity of students
return students;
```

What I have tried:

```java
List<Student> students = Stream
    .of(new Student(getRandomStringFromFile("firstnames.txt"), getRandomStringFromFile("lastnames.txt")))
    .limit(quantity)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

creates only 1 student.
2) Tried using Stream.generate, but it works only with Supplier and I can't use my arguments for the constructor.

Comment: Can you show how you have tried `Stream.generate`? You _do_ need a supplier here.

Comment: ..or think of using `IntStream.range` as if you would loop, `map`ping to a new `Student` object each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Stream.of(new Student(..))` generates a stream of **just that single element**.

What you instead want is to have a `Supplier<Student>` which can produce a random `Student`, and then use `Stream.generate(Supplier<?>)` to generate an **endless stream of random students** (which you later `limit`):

```
Supplier<Student> randomStudent = () -> new Student(
        getRandomStringFromFile("firstnames.txt"), 
        getRandomStringFromFile("lastnames.txt"));

List<Student> students = Stream.generate(randomStudent)
        .limit(quantity)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or inlined:

```
List<Student> students = Stream
        .generate(() -> new Student(
                getRandomStringFromFile("firstnames.txt"),
                getRandomStringFromFile("lastnames.txt")))
        .limit(quantity)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```